# переменные не отображаются при запросе html страницы

Tags: html, python, django

Почему переменные не отображаются  при запросе к web страницы?
**views.py**

```
def landing(request):
    name = "skyrunfest"
    current_day = "19.19.2018"
    return render(request, 'landing/landing.html')
```

**landing.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Anmiar_Finance</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

    <h1 class="title">Ломбард в г.Красноясрске</h1>
    <h1 class="title">how you, {{ name }} </h1>
    <p>Today is {{ current_day }}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: И не должны, вы же их в контекст шаблона не передали.

Comment: По факту я просто расписал то что имел введу @SergeyGornostaev

Answer (score 0):

```
def landing(request):
    name = "skyrunfest"
    current_day = "19.19.2018"
    return render(request, 'landing/landing.html', locals())
```

Функция locals() передает в контекст шаблона локальные переменные, если таковы имеются в вашей функции представления. Либо использовать свой собственный словарь со значениями переменных.

```
def landing(request):
        name = "skyrunfest"
        current_day = "19.19.2018"
        return render(request, 'landing/landing.html', {'name': name, 'current_day': current_day})
```